# How can I make sure that only on jQuery UI Tab opens at a time when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a bunch of buttons that could create a new jQuery UI tab. What I want to happen is when one is clicked only one tab is open at a time. So when another button is clicked that tab is replaced with the new tab and the other tab closes. What is the best way to accomplish this. My code is below:

here is my html:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tabs-1">My Messages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tabs-2">My Plan Messages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="overdueInquiriETab" href="#tabs-3">Overdue Messages</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tabs-4">Advance Search Results</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <table id="myMessages">
                </table>
                <div id="myMessagesPager">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">                                            
                        <table id="allMessages">
                        </table>
                        <div id="allMessagesPager"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <table id="overdueTable">
                </table>
                <div id="overduePager">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-4">
                <table id="advanceSearchTable">
                </table>
                <div id="advanceSearchPager">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
$('#quickInquirySearch').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$('#tabs li:eq(2)').show();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223346read.html', 'Message ID:2223346 ');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#modalAdvanceInquirySearch').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs li:eq(3)').show();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 3);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $("#searchPanel2").dialog("destroy");
});
$('#MMA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223345.html', 'Message ID:2223345 ');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#MMA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#MMA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#MMA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#MMA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inTaA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inTaA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});

$('#inTaA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inTaA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inTaA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inProA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inProA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inProA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inProA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#inProA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#clTa1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#clTa3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#clTa5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#clTa7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#clTa9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#AM1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#AM3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223345read.html', 'Message ID:2223345');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#AM5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#AM7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#AM9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#oveTa1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#oveTa3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
}); 
$('#oveTa5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
}); 
$('#oveTa7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
}); 
$('#oveTa9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#advSe1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#advSe3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#advSe5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#advSe7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
$('#advSe9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
});
```

Comment: Wall of code!! But where is your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to make the replace an existed tab I dynamically created with a new tab I am dynamically creating the code is below:

```
$('#advanceSearchView1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223346.html', 'Message ID:2223346 ');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#quickInquirySearch').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223346read.html', 'Message ID:2223346 ');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#modalAdvanceInquirySearch').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs li:eq(3)').show();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 3);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $("#searchPanel2").dialog("destroy");
    $('#tabs li:eq(3) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#MMA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223345.html', 'Message ID:2223345 ');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#MMA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#MMA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#MMA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#MMA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inTaA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inTaA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});

$('#inTaA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inTaA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inTaA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inProA1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inProA3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inProA5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inProA7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#inProA9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#clTa1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#clTa3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#clTa5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#clTa7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#clTa9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#AM1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#AM3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223345read.html', 'Message ID:2223345');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#AM5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#AM7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#AM9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#oveTa1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#oveTa3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#oveTa5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#oveTa7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#oveTa9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#advSe1').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223347read.html', 'Message ID:2223347');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#advSe3').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223344read.html', 'Message ID:2223344');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#advSe5').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223343read.html', 'Message ID:2223343');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#advSe7').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223342read.html', 'Message ID:2223342');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
$('#advSe9').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4)').remove();
    $("#tabs").tabs('add', 'content/2223341read.html', 'Message ID:2223341');
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 4);
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    $('#tabs ul li:eq(4) a:eq(1)').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(0) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(1) a:eq(1)').remove();
        $('#tabs ul li:eq(2) a:eq(1)').remove();
    });
});
```

If anyone knows a better way to write this please fill free to let me know.